# Should I use requestAnimationFrame to distribute calculations?

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

I have a big JS calculation that I want to complete on page load. On a decent computer the calculation takes about 5-10 seconds, which is too long because the browser freezes for that amount of time.

I can easily chop the calculation up into chunks that take about 8ms to compute. I want to render each chunk by appending it to a canvas element. Would it be wise to try and distribute these chunks using requestAnimationFrame? Are there any better alternatives perhaps (and why)?

---

***Background information:**
I'm using html2canvas to render the page to an image and then I'm blurring the image using Superfast Blur (http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlurDemo.html). The reason for this is to replicate iOS7's frosted glass effect. For more information on this see http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript .
Depending on the dimensions of the page, this takes quite some time.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to render the separate steps, you should use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. There is no point to use  `requestAnimationFrame` if you don't want to animate.

The second argument when calling `setTimeout` is the time in milliseconds that will pass before the function is called. You could set it to 1ms too, but the minimum it takes to get called is about 4ms anyways.

```
var timeoutId = 0,
    calc = function() {
        // Your calculations go here

        if(!finished) {
            timeoutId = setTimeout(calc, 4);
        }
}

calc();
```

Comment: Yes, I do want to render each step and append the rendered bit to a canvas element.